# Unable to create NX library for styles only

Tags: angular, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I am looking at the following example: https://github.com/nrwl/nx-examples/tree/nx-v5-example

I am trying to figure out how the styles library was added. What is the command I need to run?

[image]

Comment: I'm looking to create a "style library" to be able to share material themes thru multiple apps.. did you ever find a solution to you problem?